# How to check if the Activity is visible? onResume is not enough

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

One of my activity embeds `VideoView` to play some content. I implemented pausing/resuming the video in `onPause()` and `onResume()`, respectively, but to my surprise - `onResume` is called before the activity is really visible to the user.

To be exact, the scenario is as follows:

- activity is on screen, video is playing
- user locks the phone with power button
- activity gets `onPause()` called, video stops
- user presses power button
- activity gets  `onResume()` called (and thus resumes video) **before the user unlocks the screen**

I confirmed this behaviot with Android 2.2, 2.3 and 4.0. I guess it is intentionally done like that, to let the activity prepare to redraw itself immediately after locking screen goes away.

How can I detect the moment when the activity actually appears to the user? I've tried to wait for `onWindowFocusChanged(true)` being called, and it seems to work, but it doesn't make me feel perfectly safe.

Comment: According to documents, activity starts getting visible to the user in onStart() method. Your issue is quite surprising as onResume() is called after onStart().

Comment: Indeed, it was surprising to me as well! It seems that onStart/onResume are called when the activity's task is the active one (or however we call it), but lock state doesn't matter! Why simple things get so frustrating on Android? Even Symbian was less frustrating... :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to wait for the onWindowFocusChanged event as well as the OnResume event. It's a well known issue that no longer occurs in Android 4.1+. Details are available at http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/making-android-games-that-play-nice.html

Comment: That's exactly what I do now - I wait until both onResume() and and onWindowFocusChanged occur. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

In general `onResume` should be enough, but for your special case I believe you should resume the video not on `onResume()`, but when the user has unlocked his screen.

To achieve this you will need to make a `BroadcastReceiver` that listens for an intent called: `Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT`, and in `onReceive` resume your video.

> Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT:
>   Sent when the user is present after device wakes up
>   (e.g when the keyguard is gone).
>   This is a protected intent that can
>   only be sent by the system.